# Fill button.image array with MySQL image array

Tags: c#, mysql

I currently have a button with an image that's changed when a MYSQL query is called. I use:

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_Description, 
ITEM_Sale_Price, ITEM_Picture 
FROM it_titem 
WHERE ITEM_ID=207000;"
```

and

```
imgg = (byte[])(myReader["ITEM_Picture"]);
            if (imgg == null)
                iButton1.Image = null;
            else
            {

                MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(imgg);
                iButton1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mstream);
```

Let's say I have 3 buttons, and my query is an array rather than a WHERE clause. How can I apply the images to multiple buttons?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say how can I apply the images to multiple buttons in order..? how many Images are being returned in the select query..? `1`..? is there something else in your table that can distinguish the difference using an Order By clause..? what is the difference / uniqueness in regards to determining the `ITEM_Picture` to use

Comment: I mean I want each picture in my MYSQL database (ITEM_Picture) ( associated with it's key id ) to be associated with each individual button. There are about 50 rows returning, each with 1 picture.

Comment: then you need to do `Order By `ITEM_ID` then they will be in order based on `ITEM_ID` also can you show what Method / Event that code resides in.. you will need to do a While Loop in order to populate the Images properly most likely in the OnDataBound Event

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to know how to insert the MySQL images into multiple buttons

Comment: it's not that difficult I just fixed your Sql for you .. now you need to show the correct method in regards to when you want to assign the images to the button.. you are showing only partial code and there are several ways to do this but you have me at the level of `the guessing game` because you have not provided all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Query to the following

```
 SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_Description, 
 ITEM_Sale_Price, ITEM_Picture 
 FROM it_titem 
 WHERE ITEM_ID=207000 
 ORDER BY ITEM_ID;
```

here is an example of how I would load it with using a SelectedIndexChanged Event. however you will need to do this in a `OnDataBound` event or what ever event when the image is clicked I am using a datatable vs your datareader

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] arrayImage = Convert.ToByte(this.DataSet11.Tables[0].Rows[this.ListBox1.SelectedIndex]["ITEM_Picture"]);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrayImage);
    var img = this.PictureBox1;
    img.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    img.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
}
```